# Is it possible to hint to the client browser to use a different soft keyboard for input boxes on a web page?

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-phone, soft-keyboard

Some OSes (e.g. windows 8, Windows Phone) have the ability for native apps to specify what a field will contain, and hint at which soft keyboard to display. Is it possible to add these hints to regular web pages to show (for example) the email address optimised soft keyboard, or the phone number optimised soft keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use HTML5 input types to hint to the OS as to which keyboard should be displayed.

There are numerous webpages out there that [list all the new HTML5 input types](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/html5-input-types/) and [show examples of how they look](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/) [on different platforms](http://szaboka.hu/articles/power-up-your-forms-with-html5-input-types/).

Windows Phone 7, which uses IE9, does **not** support these newer HTML5 input types.

Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 **do** as they use IE10.

For a full list of feature support, there's a [comparison chart from quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html) and [another on wufoo.com](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/)

Comment: Are there ways to hint to the browser on more rich inputs? For example, if using something like http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ to provide formatting help to the user, the input type still has to be "text" to accomplish the display within the field. It would be great if another attribute hint were available to still hint no matter the input type.

Comment: @NeilMonroe you might have to post a new question, that answer is quite old and might not apply to Windows 10, for example.

Comment: My comment was directed more towards mobile users, where an on-screen keyboard may be the input source. As you say, though, there is probably merit in making my question it's own post. Thanks for the input, @NeilTurner.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the same things for a web page by using one of the 13 new "input" types in HTML5. For example, if you specify "email" as an input type, IE10 Metro on Windows 8 will provide a soft keyboard that has the "@" and ".com" easily accessible. Specify "tel", and Windows Phone 8 will bring up a telephone-like keypad.

You can find out more here: [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **inputmode** attribute ([spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#input-modalities:-the-inputmode-attribute)) if you do not want to change the **type** attribute for any reason. This should also work for elements other than **input**, such as **textarea** or any element with **contenteditable**.